# How to execute a jar file in node js application

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jar

I had a node js application and I want to execute a very basic jar file which has `System.out.println("Hello");` So that I need to capture that result in one variable.How can we do this.
I tried this

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar ./TestFile.jar',
function (error, stdout, stderr){
console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
if(error !== null){
  console.log("Error -> "+error);
}
});
module.exports = child;
```

But it is giving me error as

```
Output ->
Error -> Error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -jar ./TestFile.jar"
no main manifest attribute, in ./TestFile.jar
```

Can someone help how can we run this jar file so that I can display that result on my client side.

Comment: That looks like an issue with the JAR manifest rather than your Node code. Have you tried running `java -jar ./TestFile.jar` manually?

Answer (score 4):

You obviously haven't specified a `Main-Class` in your jar's manifest so you can't run it via `java -jar`. See [here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) for more info.

If not using a `Main-Class` entry in your jar's manifest, you'll need to run via

```
java -cp ./TestFile.jar com.foo.MyMainClass
```

Comment: my jar file accepts multiple parameter , how to get these input from HTML.